# False Assumption in Rank Calculation - Flawed Argument?

Tags: linear-algebra, logic

I've gotten an exam back, and I think I've found somewhere that I can snag some marks, but I'm not sure about the quality of the argument presented in the question.

Let $B$ be a matrix that is obtained from changing the value of exactly one entry of a matrix $A$. Then $rankB$ has one of three possible values: $rankA−1$, $rankA$, or $rankA+1$.

This was a true or false question, which I answered as being false. This is because there are such counterexamples as the zero matrix, whose rank is zero. It is impossible for a matrix to have a rank of -1. Since three values are not possible, the statement is false. During the assessment, I asked my professor about what the exact argument of this statement was, and he said that it was "There are 3 possible values, *and* it is one of them". It seems to me that this asserts 2 points - one regarding the existence of 3 values, one regarding value itself. Since I can show that there are not necessarily 3 possible values, I think that this negates the statement.

Is my reasoning correct? Could someone provide some insight as to why or why not?

Comment: For what it's worth:  I don't think the problem requires that all three possibilities be possible in all cases.  I, therefore, agree with your professor that it suffices to show that, in all cases, the answer is one of those three possibilities (which it is).  I would not even think it was necessary to show that all three cases could in fact arise.

Comment: For instance, I think the following theorem is true:  "If $n\in \mathbb N$ is a perfect number than either $n$ is odd or $n=2^n\times (2^n-1)$ where $2^n-1$ is prime".  And that it remains true even if somebody someday shows that the odd case is not possible.

Comment: The problem, along with the clarification that my professor provided, assert that 3 values *are* possible.

Comment: There is nothing in the problem statement that requires that you show that all three cases are actually possible.  Only that the answer is always one of those three.  In any case, all three of those answers are possible, just not in all cases.

Comment: If I can provide a counterexample, such as the zero matrix, does that not make the statement false ?

Comment: As we have said, we do not believe your example is a counterexample.  We do not believe the problem statement to require that all three "possible answers" be possible in all cases.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not agree with your reading.

The statement asserts that, *regardless* of what $A$ is, the resulting matrix will have a rank which is one of the three options. It does *not* assert that each of the options are possible in any particular circumstance, nor does it assert that that all three options are always achievable.

That is, you are trying to read the statement as saying that for any $A$, you will be able to change the value of one entry in one way so that the resulting matrix has rank $\mathrm{rank}(A)-1$, in some other way so the ranks are equal, and in some third way so the rank of the resulting matrix is $\mathrm{rank}(A)+1$. The statement does not assert that; to assert that, you would need an extra clause saying something like “... and all three possibilities will be achievable.” The statement does not make the two assertions you think it does, it only makes one: that $$\mathrm{rank}(A)-1\leq\mathrm{rank}(B)\leq\mathrm{rank}(A)+1.$$
That assertion is true.

**Added.** You say in comments that the professor said that “and it is one of them” is implied in the statement. Yes; but it does not imply “and each one of the three possibilities can occur”, which is what you read into it.

What you have is an implication: the premise is “you change one of the entries of $A$” and the consequent is “the rank will be equal to the rank of $A$, to the rank of $A$ minus $1$, or to the rank of $A$ plus $1$”. What you read into the problem was an extra clause saying that, *plus* “and each of the three possibilities will occur.”

---

The kind of statement you read in is worthwhile: it’s usually signaled by words like “and this is best possible”, “and all possibilities can occur”, and the like. Without them, it does not do that.

---

Having said that, let me say (as I usually do) that going over the exam to see “where [you] can snag some marks” is... exactly the attitude least likely to get you any sympathy from a professor, and exactly the wrong attitude if your objective is to actually *learn*. You should be looking to understand what you did wrong, why it is wrong, and how to do it right in the future. If you want to go in and explain that this was your reasoning, and ask why, in the professor’s opinion, it is incorrect, go for it. But do so to explain yourself and try to understand why the professor agrees or does not agree with you; do not do so because you are hoping to squeeze some extra credit out of them.

Comment: +1 for what's below the last horizontal rule.

Comment: Upon clarification with my professor, he told me that the question states that "3 values are possible *and* it is one of them". As for the extra marks part, my wording was likely misleading with how casual it was. I am not interested in gaining more marks, but rather with the nuances of such logic - namely how the argument is built and proven. My apologies for any misunderstanding.

Comment: @dnfost: “And it is one of them” is not the same thing as “and each of them is possible”, which is what you are reading into the problem.

Comment: Again, I'll refer to what my prof said during the exam: "3 values are possible *and* it is one of them". Is this just a nuance of the language ?

Comment: @dnfost: Yes: “and it is one of them” is not the same thing as “and each of them can happen.” If I toss a coin, the result will be either heads, or tails, or balanced on an edge, or hang in midair, and one of those possibliities *will* occur. That is a true statement. If I said “and each of the possibilities can be achieved”, well, then assuming Newton/Einstein is right, then I am no longer correct. Saying “and it *is* one of them” does not assert that **each** possibility **will** necessarily happen. Just that whatever happens, it will be one of the possibilities listed.

Comment: @dnfost: Less verbose” 3 values are possible *and* it is one of them” just asserts that one of them *will* happen, not that *each* of them will happen.

Comment: @dnfost: P.S. I’m glad that what you wrote was not the actual attitude you went in with. I’ll keep the comment there, for future generations, even though it does not apply to you.

Comment: That makes sense - thanks for your patience ! I find that the most difficult part of math is making sense of the English around it. Since this was an exam question, I'll be taking the post down in about an hour (in case they choose to put this on future exams, which may be online). I appreciate your help.

Comment: @dnfost: Please don’t do that unless your professor specifically asks you to (check with them if you want). This site is supposed to be a repository of questions and answers, not a snap-chat-for-math.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll check in with him closer to the exam date, hopefully the exams will just be in person by then.